# Should a special issue follow the regular frequency of the journal or separately?

Tags: journals, special-issue

If a quarterly journal wants to publish a special issue, should it be published as an additional issue or it should replace a regular seasonal issue? Are there any guidelines on this or it's a matter that depends on the journal's policies?

Comment: What do you mean by "should"? It's entirely up to the journal. They can publish as often or as rarely as they please.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: In some countries, there are legal bodies that set regulations on publishing and oversee them. Moreover,  there are other subtleties. For example, if you're a subscription journal, how should you price the extra issue? Should you include it in the annual membershib package? Is it accepted that you publish a special issue instead of a regular issue? I'm asking for the best practice in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both ways are possible, but usually they are called differently. If the issue is replacing a regular issue, it is called **special issue**.

If the issue is added to the standard set of issues, making an extra one, it is usually called **supplement**. And even here the conventions differ; some supplements are published with a regular issue, and some are published separately. Most often, they are numbered as `1S`, `1A` or alike, but form an integral part of the volume.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, special issues replace regular issues. Sometimes a special issue may have a part dedicated to regular papers.

To make an example, [this webpage](http://iopscience.iop.org/0026-1394/page/Special%20issues) lists the special issues of the journal *Metrologia* (a monthly journal): you can see that those issues follow the regular numbering.

Comment: This has been my experience as well.

Comment: I don't suppose this is always the case, Mr. Ortolano.